# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘friend’

Tags: c++, class, scope, function-definition, friend-function

In my .cpp file I got

```
Student:: friend istream& operator>>(istream &input,Student &a){
       input>>a.AM>>a.name>>a.semester>>;
       return input;
   }
```

And in my .h file I got

```
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input,Student &a);
```

I keep getting that error and I don't know what to do.Any help?

Comment: The operator function isn't part of class Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the definition like

```
istream& operator>>(istream &input,Student &a){
   input>>a.AM>>a.name>>a.semester>>;
   return input;
}
```

The specifier friend is used only in a declaration of a friend function within a class.

And a friend function is not a member of the class granting friendship.

Comment: Compiled perfectly.Thank you a lot for you time and help!

Comment: @LyprandosLiatsos Please mark the answer with the green checkmark

Comment: My apologies,Im new here.